# Is it the right meaning: „Ich will keine Vergiftung verursachen, aber ich vermisse dich.“ - "I don’t want to make you intoxicated, but I miss you."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am looking for a proper translation of "I don’t want to make you intoxicated, but I miss you."
My translation is „Ich will keine Vergiftung verursachen, aber ich vermisse dich.“ -
I am thinking about an intoxication of body and mind - is the translation accurate?

It's not about "arousal", on the contrary: When there is a lot of something, intoxication can occur. In this case, by me. If there are a lot of me, I will be intrusive. Here is my version of the German sentence with a bit more context: „Ich werde nicht, Wie oft darf ich schreiben. Ich will keine Vergiftung verursachen, aber ich vermisse dich.“

Comment: Neither the German nor the English sentence make a lot of sense to me. Are you translating from English to German?

Comment: Just to make a stab at the meaning you'd like to convey: "Intoxicate" can mean "to excite or elate to the point of enthusiasm or frenzy" ([Merriam-Webster 1b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intoxicate)). Is this your intention? *In certain contexts* I'd translate the verb with "berauschen" (in analogy with alcoholic beverages), "betören" (an intoxicating scent, "betörender Duft"). – This just as an attempt to clarify :)

Comment: Along the other comments: please provide more context and situation around the text, and clarify the question and especially the direction of translation

Comment: No, it's not about "arousal", on the contrary. When there is a lot of something, intoxication can occur. In this case, by me. if there are a lot of me, I will be intrusive. Here is the sentence: „Ich werde nicht, Wie oft darf ich schreiben. Ich will keine Vergiftung verursachen, aber ich vermisse dich.“

Comment: @planetmaker: Auch Du bist eingeladen formulierte Schließungsgründe mit formalen Schließungsbegehren zu begleiten.

Comment: I don't like to be too quick about it and give especially new users a chance to improve their question. Adding the context from the comment to the question makes it much clearer

Comment: @Anfisa please check that I did not accidentally edited your question detrimentally. Edit it directly to correct or expand

Comment: First, I don't see how this isn't a translation request. Also, I agree with @idmean; the meaning is clear in English so it's hard to know what you're trying to say in German. From your explanation perhaps you're trying to say something like "I don't want to be clingy, ..." Perhaps "*anhänglich*" would work as a translation.

Comment: @planetmaker thank you very much for help and the correction, that's right. English is also not my native language and it is unusual for me to express myself in it. Thank everyone for the answers and advice. A very interesting resource for sharing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the context given of the fear that a person might get too much from the presence of another person: I think neither intoxication in English is a particularly good choice for its different connotations, but German 'Vergiftung' is even stronger and always negative (a poissoning, not an intoxication which can be seen as positive effect of a drug) and indicates a clinical illness from a too much of a substance.

In the context of a relationship between two people I would expect something along the lines of

> Ich möchte dir nicht zur Last fallen, aber... (I don't want to be a burden to you, but...)

> Ich möchte dich nicht belästigen, nur... (I don't want to harass you, but...)

If you need it dramatic, a sometimes used metaphor is 'ersticken' (to stifle /suffocate / smother):

> Ich möchte dich nicht ersticken, aber... (I don't want to suffocate you, but...)

Answer (score 1):

Im Deutschen spricht man auch von einer vergifteten Stimmung, guten Laune oder Beziehung, aber ohne nähere Präzisierung, was am anderen vergiftet werden könnte ist die Formulierung im Deutschen unverständlich.

"Ich will Dich nicht bedrängen" kann im Deutschen nicht durch "... vergiften" ausgedrückt werden, auch "Ich möchte mich nicht Überdosieren" - eigentlich ein guter Fund von HalvarF - wird in diesem Sinne nicht genutzt.

Comment: No, it's not about "arousal", on the contrary. When there is a lot of something, intoxication can occur. In this case, by me. if there are a lot of me, I will be intrusive. Here is the sentence: „Ich werde nicht, Wie oft darf ich schreiben. Ich will keine Vergiftung verursachen, aber ich vermisse dich.“

Comment: *Vergiftung* in German means poisoning. IMHO it does not make sense in this context.

Comment: @Anfisa: "Arousal" habe ich auch nicht verstanden, aber ich verstehe nun besser, wie der Ausdruck überhaupt gemeint ist.

Comment: @RHa: Und `toxic` bedeutet nicht `giftig`, oder geht Dein Kommentar gar nicht an mich? Hier sind so fancy `@`-Symbole …

Answer (score 0):

Ich think "Vergiftung" is hard to understand as "too much of something" here, I think you would have to explain that you mean that in some way.

A different word you could maybe use is "die Überdosis" (overdose) or "überdosieren" (to overdose) or (less associated with illegal drugs) "Überdosierung".

> Ich will keine Überdosierung verursachen, aber ich vermisse dich.

could maybe work and be an understandable metaphor to an intelligent person. It's not idiomatic to use it that way of course, so it can still be misunderstood.